# I want to start Java Stand alone(Swing) application without dos prompt to open?

Tags: java

I want to run a Java Stand Alone application(Swing) without the command prompt window to open.
How to achieve it?
Another question is
i want my login screen on the top of an Background Image file.
How to achieve this?
Pl. give me example code also.

Comment: Never post your email address in questions.

Comment: Never ask more than one question as part of a single question.

Comment: Always show the work you have done so far.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to answer the first question....

In Windows create a bat file

```
@echo off
start javaw  -jar [jarfile]
exit
```